# Razor Pages Multiple Row Update

Tags: c#, razor, razor-pages

I have the following code in Index.cshtml.cs (this is not MVC)

```
[BindProperty]
public Inventory MyInventory { get; set; }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostClearAllAsync()
{
   MyInventory = await _context.Inventory.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Current_State != "DEPLOYED");
   MyInventory.Verify = "0";
   _context.Attach(MyInventory).State = EntityState.Modified;
   await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
   return RedirectToPage("./Index");
}
```

The code works fine but only for a single row (first occurrence). I would to update all rows where Current_State != "DEPLOYED". Please help and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my own problem, here it is:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostClearAllAsync()
{
   var result = await _context.Inventory.Where(m => m.Current_State != "DEPLOYED").ToListAsync();
   foreach (var item in result)
   {
      item.Verify = "0";
      _context.Attach(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
   }
   await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
   return RedirectToPage("./Index");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it will be better to provide more details, where condition will through all Inventory context

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostClearAllAsync()
{
   MyInventory = await _context.Inventory.Where(m => m.Current_State.ToLower() != 
   "deployed");
   MyInventory.Verify = "0";
   _context.Attach(MyInventory).State = EntityState.Modified;
   await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
   return RedirectToPage("./Index");
 }
```

Comment: @Peter , please inform me by the result of this answer

Comment: Here is what I am getting after changing "FirstOrDefaultAsync" to "Where": 'IQuaryable<Inventory>' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'IQuaryable<Inventory>' could be found.